# d3.js data binding needing a unique key for duplicate entries from csv file

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, coffeescript

The code is modified form [Jim Vallandingham's 'Building a Bubble Cloud'](https://github.com/vlandham/bubble_cloud), available on github.

Data in csv:

```
"miller","husband"
"miller","wife"
"shulz","husband"
```

with .data(data, function(d) {return idValue(d);}); - where idValue(d) relates to the first column ( has to be that way for other reasons )

Where rows contain duplicate entries in column one (here: 'miller, miller' ) the second row is being returned as 'null' in labelEnter. Why ?

```
updateLabels = function(d) {


label = labelG.selectAll(".bubble-label")
              .data(data, function(d) {return idValue(d);});

label.exit().remove();

labelEnter = label.enter()
                  .append("a")
                  .attr("class", "bubble-label")
                  .attr("href", function(d) {return "#" + (encodeURIComponent(idValue(d)));})
                  .call(force.drag)
                  .call(connectEvents);
```

breakpoints:

```
label - array with [42] entries 
label.exit().remove(); - array with [0] entries
labelEnter - array with [42] entries, rows 'duplic_in_col1' returned as 'null'
```

**EDIT:** from the responses of Tom and Cool Blue, I learned that an individual key is needed for each page element to be displayable. In this example 'miller' appears twice as a key used for binding, and is used once only ( see Tom's first comment ). This answers my initial question.

If I use .data(data) instead, then the array index is used for the data binding. 'miller' and 'miller' will then each have their own index and both will be displayed as a page element. This works as well and is reflected in Coll Blue's answer.

However, - new information -, the design includes a removeBubble function on click where the key of a bubble needs to be known:

```
 removeBubble = (d) ->
 currentId = idValue(d)
 data = data.filter (e) -> idValue(e) != currentId
 update()
 d3.event.preventDefault()
```

To preserve this function, I decided to add a column to my file.csv and use the entries as an individual key:

```
"col1","col2","col3"
"1","miller","husband"
"2",""miller","wife"
"3",""shulz","husband"
```

the data binding on the first column with .data(data, function (d) { return d.col1;}) and apply this change to the removeBubble function as well (d.col1) to identify the bubble that is clicked on for removal.

This is not a d3.js solution which would be to create a unique key. How to to that is found in the answers below.

Comment: the second argument of data() needs to return a unique value, each appended page element will be associated to a given data element based on this value. The easiest thing to do would be to leave this element blank so the join is done on the array index. Aside: As someone reading the code I would expect something referred to as an id (as in idValue) to be unique, perhaps a different name would help with reasoning about the code too.

Comment: @TomP if you are only using the enter selection then it's a problem, but _after_ enter is called the update and enter selections are merged and it's no longer a problem. But anyway, it's not really clear what the design intent is behind the key so you are probably on the money.

Comment: @CoolBlue true, your answer will work for the question but it's not unusual to change the order or content of data and re-call enter(), in which case the results may not be what's wanted.

Comment: @Tom P you're bang on mate (unlike my original answer).

Comment: @ Tom P , @Cool Blue. I appreciate your comments and am working with your suggestions. At this point I see an irregular behavior in the update of the label values as it resets a different label to the string that was clicked on; thus some more work to understand enter() will be needed. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @EdDie I would just suggest that in future you post your complete code. That's the best way to express thanks to the community here. :). It's actually a good idea to imagine that you hit this question with Google and think about what would be useful from that point of view. Good luck!

Comment: @Cool Blue, I agree. I always think that the code is too long and then nobody will read it. The code is modified form Jim Vallandingham's 'Building a Bubble Cloud' - when you click on a bubble, it disappears: I guess that is why the key function is important, if I take it away the entire set is update on click. I have to reread to understand it better.

Comment: The code is only too long if you are not doing it right ;)  if you are having trouble with understanding data keys, then make a small project to focus on this feature (a minimum working example). If you follow this approach then, 80% of the time you will figure it out for yourself.  The other 20% you can post here as a question with a minimum working example.  The best way to handle your particular issue is to have a key function that produces a unique key from the data.  I will update my answer to show how...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Fix the symptom

To get it working try this...

```
updateLabels = function(d) {

//UPDATE SELECTION
label = labelG.selectAll(".bubble-label")
    .data(data, function(d) {return idValue(d);});

//EXIT SELECTION
label.exit().remove();

//ENTER SELECTION
labelEnter = label.enter();

//MERGED UPDATE+ENTER SELECTIONS
label.append("a")
    .attr("class", "bubble-label")
    .attr("href", function(d) {return "#" + (encodeURIComponent(idValue(d)));})
    .call(force.drag)
    .call(connectEvents);
```

I suggest studying [this series of examples](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218) very carefully.

It's not really clear what you are trying to achieve with the key function so rather than try to figure that out, I made it irrelevant using the above pattern.  @Tom P is correct though: if the key is not unique then it doesn't really make sense and his suggestion to leave it out will also solve the problem. 
The complete solution is to make a unique key and use the patterns employed in the examples I linked above.

When you have non-unique keys, if there are nodes already present with the matching keys, the first node will be put in the update selection and the rest in the enter selection. If you are only adding features on the enter selection (as in the OP code) then the first node will not be included. So if there are two nodes with the same key, then the first one will be left out. In the above solution, the features are added on the update selection *after* the enter selection has been called. As stated in the documentation and the examples, the enter method has the side effect of merging itself into the update selection, so the changes are made on all nodes, regardless of the key.

---

### Fix the architecture

Taking it to the next level, you can create a key function that returns a unique key for each record, in other words, assuming your data is like this...

`[ ["miller","husband"], ["millsbaner","wife"], ["shulz","husband"], ... ]`

The key could simply be `d.join("_");`

Now, read [this](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data),
especially this part ...

> The key function is called twice during the data binding process,
>   which proceeds in two phases.
>
> 1. The *key* function is evaluated on the nodes to form `nodeByKeyValue` (an associative array of nodes) with the `this`
>      context as the node, `d` as the node `__data__` member and the the
>      second argument `i` as the selection group index.
> 2. The *key* function is evaluated on each element of the *values* array - this time with *values* as the `this` context, *values*[`i`]
>      as the first argument `d` and the *values* index `i` as the second
>      argument - and the results are then used to attempt to look up the
>      nodes in the `nodeByKeyValue` collection.  If the lookup is
>      successful, the node is added to the *update selection*, any nodes not
>      queried are added to the exit selection.  Any data elements that
>      failed to find a matching node are used to form the enter selection.

It's important to understand that, if you change the value of the contents of one of the elements of your data array, e.g. `data[0][0] = "Smith"`, then the data bound to the DOM element will also change (e.g. the value returned by `.text(function(d){ return idValue(d) }` or `.datum()`, will also be updated). Why?  Because the value bound to the DOM element is a *reference* to the `data[0][0]`, object, not it's *contents*.
So you have to be careful.
If you are changing your data by pushing new records into it then this is not a problem.  But, the safest way is to make a key that avoids this problem.

One way to do this is to include the function that transforms the data into DOM element attributes in your key.  For example...

```
function idValue(d) {
    return d.join("_");
}  
function encodeURI(d) {
    return "#" + encodeURIComponent(idValue(d));
}  


updateLabels = function(d) {

    //UPDATE SELECTION
    label = labelG.selectAll(".bubble-label")
        .data(data, function(d) {
            return Array.isArray(this) ? encodeURI(d)
                                       : d3.select(this).attr("href");
    });

    //EXIT SELECTION
    label.exit().remove();

    //ENTER SELECTION
    labelEnter = label.enter()
        .append("a")
        .attr("class", "bubble-label");
        .attr("href", encodeURI)
        .call(force.drag)
        .call(connectEvents);
```

So now, when `.data` is parsing the nodes, it will make the key from their `href` attribute and when, in the second phase of the data binding, it parses the data array, it will return the href value constructed from the data.  So, even if you have changed the contents of one of your data elements, it will still show a mismatch on the key and that element will be placed in the enter selection and your original pattern will be fine.

Comment: same 'null' returns. When I change the data key function return idValue(d) to  d.col2 then I get different 'null' returns, but they still reflect duplicate entries. I want to bind on all rows without skipping the rows where cell_row_x has a duplicate entry.

Comment: I didn't suggest changing the data key function. Paste your revised code please.

Comment: @ Cool Blue. Correct, you didn't, I added that as background info. The solution is .data(data) without specifying the key as this will return a key for each row automatically.

Comment: @EdDie, true. OR use a unique key and my original answer OR the above answer in its current form. But anyway, the best explanation is in the link I included.

Comment: @ Tom P   please see the edit of my question. Thank both of you very much for your time.

Comment: I was hoping for a response that would show how to create a unique key. This is a great solution. The added column in the csv works as well naturally, but your solution adds the next level and is therefor a treat. The documentation is a bit dense for a beginner. Thank you.

Comment: No problem @EdDie, if any part of it is unclear please let me know and I will attempt to edit it.